# jquerymobile selectmenu fails

Tags: sqlite, html, jquery-mobile

i'm trying to create a categories list with Jquerymobile-html5 and websql/sqlite.

i post my code here to hope someone sees what i do wrong.

```
    //load the cats to choose a cat 
function loadCatOptions() {

var option_str='';
option_str += '<option value="0" data-placeholder="true">Choose categorie</option>';
//option_str += '<option value="0">Top/ParentiD</option>';



db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM categories', [], function (tx, results) {

var len = results.rows.length, i;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

var r = results.rows.item(i);

var catID = r.categories_id;
}
var count =0;
while (count < catID+1){
count;

tx.executeSql('SELECT c.parent_id, c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.categories_image FROM categories c, categories_description cd WHERE c.categories_id ='+  count  +' AND cd.categories_id ='+  count  +' and cd.language_id ="1"  ORDER BY sort_order, cd.categories_name', [], function (tx, results) {


var len = results.rows.length, i;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

var r2 = results.rows.item(i);



option_str += "<option value=" +  r2['categories_id']  + ">" +  r2['categories_name']  + "</option>";
console.log('categoriesname='+ r2['categories_name']);
$("#parent_id").html(option_str).selectmenu('refresh', true);
}

});
count++;

}



});
});           
}
```

<s>The consolelog shows all items by its name, so i'm sure that the database query is correct.
I might have spend days to someting what wasnt the problem at all.
if i take only the SELECT * query and call the selectmenu, i can see all categorie_id's in the list (ofcourse replace categories_name by categories_id to got that to work).
So the problem now is with jquerymobile??????????????</s>

It wont read the option_str += inside the second database query!
aaargg

Code above is updated with the fix.

Comment: You should remove the solution from the question and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question:

**Problem fixed**

old code:

```
option_str += "<option value=" +  r2['categories_id']  + ">" +  r2['categories_name']      + "</option>";
console.log('categoriesname='+ r2['categories_name']);
}

});
count++;

}

$("#parent_id").html(option_str).selectmenu('refresh', true);//Moved below closing tag of count++

});
});           
}
```